# zsh - variable expansion fails in nested functions

Tags: function, variables, zsh

I defined a nested function in my `.zshrc` hoping to define multiple similar zsh functions :

```sh
makefunc_gman () {
    local MAN_SEC_LIST=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8) 
    for GMAN_SEC in ${MAN_SEC_LIST}
    do
        "gman${GMAN_SEC}" () {
            gdir_C "$1" "man${GMAN_SEC}" 
        }
    done
}

makefunc_gman # calls the function
```

- The functions I wanted to define the function above are `gman1`, `gman2` to `gman8`.
- I want to get a function named `gman1` which calls `gdir_C "$1" man1` after sourcing this function above.
- `gdir_C` in the code is another function defined in `.zshrc`.

But when I sourced `.zshrc`, `where gman1` gave me this:

```
$ where gman1        
gman1 () {
    local MAN_GMAN_SEC="man${GMAN_SEC}" 
    gdir_C "$1" "man${GMAN_SEC}"
}
```

It seemed that the variable `$GMAN_SEC` in this nested function is not expanded. How do I get the variable to expand correctly? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use `eval`, as `zsh` doesn't have nested scopes or closures.

```
makefunc_gman () {
    local MAN_SEC_LIST=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8) 
    for GMAN_SEC in ${MAN_SEC_LIST}
    do
        eval "gman${GMAN_SEC} () {
            gdir_C \"\$1\" man${GMAN_SEC}
        }"
    done
}
```